# JQTouch load remote html

Tags: jquery, iphone, cordova, jqtouch

How can i load a remote url in to jqtouch application. I tried to load using iframe, it's works in mac safari. But it is not working in iPhone using Phonegap. is there any other method to load remote html to Jqtouch app?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the UIWebView to load internal and external html pages. If you don't wan't to mess around with to much objective-c, you can use the ChildBrowser plugin for PhoneGap. There is an excellent tutorial on how to implement it here:

http://hiediutley.com/2011/03/30/phonegap-tutorial-series-4-using-a-third-party-plugin/

Hope it helps.